# How to extract value from duplicate tags from XML using sql developer

Tags: sql, xml, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to extract value of `<CallID>` tag from XML column of oracle table.
But in my XML, the tag `<CallID>` is twice and it will have always same value.

I used below query to get output:

```
select extractvalue(extract(xmltype(body),'//CallID'),'//CallID')
from table123;
```

But I get error "ExtractValue returns value of only one node"

How can I get the value of CallID tag in pl/sql developer?

```
<Update Destination="ABC" CreatedBy="NETWORK">
    <Assignment>
        <Comment/>
        <Engineers>
            <Value Key="0">
                <Engineer>
                    <ID>123</ID>
                    <Team>
                        <Name>12345</Name>
                    </Team>
                </Engineer>
            </Value>
        </Engineers>
        <Finish>2014-11-07 09:35:00</Finish>
        <Key>123456</Key>
        <Location/>
        <Revision>3</Revision>
        <Stamp>
            <CreatedBy>Customer</CreatedBy>
            <CreatingProcess>0</CreatingProcess>
            <ModifiedBy>NETWORK</ModifiedBy>
            <ModifyingProcess>632753</ModifyingProcess>
            <TimeCreated>2014-11-03 13:24:14</TimeCreated>
            <TimeModified>2014-11-06 12:49:14</TimeModified>
        </Stamp>
        <Start>2014-11-07 07:45:00</Start>
        <Task>
            <CallID>977277212</CallID>
            <ModifiedByTorUser/>
        </Task>
    </Assignment>
    <PrevAssignment>
        <Assignment>
            <Comment/>
            <Engineers>
                <Value Key="0">
                    <Engineer>
                        <ID>123</ID>
                        <Team>
                            <Name>12345</Name>
                        </Team>
                    </Engineer>
                </Value>
            </Engineers>
            <Finish>2014-11-07 09:50:00</Finish>
            <Key>123456</Key>
            <Location/>
            <Revision>3</Revision>
            <Stamp>
                <CreatedBy>Customer</CreatedBy>
                <CreatingProcess>0</CreatingProcess>
                <ModifiedBy>NETWORK</ModifiedBy>
                <ModifyingProcess>632753</ModifyingProcess>
                <TimeCreated>2014-11-03 13:24:14</TimeCreated>
                <TimeModified>2014-11-06 12:49:14</TimeModified>
            </Stamp>
            <Start>2014-11-07 08:00:00</Start>
            <Task>
                <CallID>977277212</CallID>
                <ModifiedByTorUser/>
                <Number>0</Number>
                <SlaStatus>0</SlaStatus>
            </Task>
        </Assignment>
    </PrevAssignment>
</Update>
```

Comment: You have 2 `<CallID>` element in the sample XML. If you want only one of them, try `//CallID[1]` or `//CallID[2]`. (disclaimer : I'm no oracle expert, not even routine user of it)

Comment: Thanks har07 for suggestion, I used below query to get desired result: select extractvalue(extract(xmltype(body),'//CallID[1]'),'//CallID[2]')
from table123;  Actually, I was looking for single query to get 'CallID' value irrespective of occurance of <CallID> in XML. The above query does not work with single <CallID> in XML.